# SQL Database on Virtual Box

Tags: sql, virtualbox

У меня есть база данных(H2 Console) , запущенная на виртуальной машине (Windows) .
Мне не же требуется законектиться к ней на своей основной машине (Mac).
Использую VirtualBox.

Comment: А в чём состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как законектиться к ней на своей основной машине??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Вас нужно настроить вашу сеть в virtualbox в режим Bridge. Тут описано что это такое. http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/vm/VirtualBox-networking.html

И соответственно настроить слушать вашу БД на этот ip адрес.  Например вы настроите сеть в virtualbox на 192.168.1.50 и в конфиге БД тоже должен быть этот ip адрес а не 127.0.0.1 как обычно бывает